# Flutter Custom Animated Icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking to make a item that gets added and removed from list.

what I am looking for is to have the + icon and the - icon and animate between the 2 for a clean and smooth look.

I have the following code

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
            child: AnimatedIcon(
              icon: AnimatedIcons.home_menu,
              progress: _animationController,
              color: Colors.white,
            ))
```

with

```
void _handleOnPressed() {
setState(() {
  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  isPlaying
      ? _animationController.forward()
      : _animationController.reverse();
  });
}
```

This for fine for the built in animated icons in flutter.

I am looking to use the + and the - icon, but with the same look.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, atleast for me. Any demo of what you're trying to achieve or atleast screenshot of your issue?

Comment: Sure https://medium.com/@bimsina/animated-icons-in-flutter-3ca7e921500a is exactly what I am trying to achieve... just with my own icons and not the ones built into the AnimatedIcons. They have a set type of icon and I wont work for what I am doing. I have mimicked the code here... works great, but not the 2 icons I want. My basic question is CAN i use my own icons to achieve the same affect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're in luck my friend! Flutter already has you covered with AnimatedIcon()

[AnimatedIcon Class in the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html)

[Animated Icon Widget of the week Video](https://youtu.be/pJcbh8pbvJs)

Now to animate your Icons with Flare. Jeff Delaney made a good tutorial for this.

https://fireship.io/lessons/animated-navigation-flutter-flare/

Comment: I know, and as stated, using the animated icon is fine if you want their selected icons. But I want my own icons, I want to know how to use mine instead of theirs. The affect that they have works great for their icons...just not for what I want.

Comment: You can always CMD/Ctrl click through AnimatedIcons.someIcon to see how they were created and make your own if the linked tutorial doesn't get you going to where you wanna be.

Comment: "watch this tutorial" isn't a good answer. It's AN answer but not a good one.

Answer (score 33):

I know it's not as beautiful as [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html), but you could actually get very similar transition with any 2 icons of your choice with just a few lines of code:

```
 IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          transitionBuilder: (child, anim) => RotationTransition(
                turns: child.key == ValueKey('icon1')
                    ? Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0.75).animate(anim)
                    : Tween<double>(begin: 0.75, end: 1).animate(anim),
                child: FadeTransition(opacity: anim, child: child),
              ),
          child: _currIndex == 0
              ? Icon(Icons.close, key: const ValueKey('icon1'))
              : Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  key: const ValueKey('icon2'),
                )),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _currIndex = _currIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        });
      },
    );
```

Result:
[image: result]

---

Or you can use `ScaleTransition` instead of `FadeTransition`, and get even more similar animation:

```
IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          transitionBuilder: (child, anim) => RotationTransition(
                turns: child.key == ValueKey('icon1')
                    ? Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0.75).animate(anim)
                    : Tween<double>(begin: 0.75, end: 1).animate(anim),
                child: ScaleTransition(scale: anim, child: child),
              ),
          child: _currIndex == 0
              ? Icon(Icons.close, key: const ValueKey('icon1'))
              : Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  key: const ValueKey('icon2'),
                )),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _currIndex = _currIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        });
      },
    )
```

Result:
[image: result-2]

---

With this approach you could use any icons you want, and it doesn't require creating separate `AnimationController` just to control the transition, unlike [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html)

Comment: This answer saved my day two times already

Answer (score 5):

Flutter is providing [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html) can be use, This is an example how to use it.

```dart
class _CreatePackageViewState extends State<CreatePackageView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {  
       bool expanded = true;
       late AnimationController controller;
      @override
       void initState() {
        super.initState();
        controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        );
      }



      IconButton(
            icon: AnimatedIcon(
              icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
              progress: controller,
              semanticLabel: 'Show menu',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                expanded ? controller.forward() : controller.reverse();
                expanded = !expanded;
              });
            }),

    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use  `animate_icons 2.0.0` package to animate two icons

```
AnimateIcons(
    startIcon: Icons.add_circle,
    endIcon: Icons.add_circle_outline,
    size: 100.0,
    controller: controller,
    // add this tooltip for the start icon
    startTooltip: 'Icons.add_circle',
    // add this tooltip for the end icon
    endTooltip: 'Icons.add_circle_outline',
    size: 60.0,
    onStartIconPress: () {
        print("Clicked on Add Icon");
        return true;
    },
    onEndIconPress: () {
        print("Clicked on Close Icon");
        return true;
    },
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    startIconColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    endIconColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    clockwise: false,
),
```

https://pub.dev/packages/animate_icons

[image: ref image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Flutter team use a command line tool called vitool to convert SVGs to paths that can be consumed as an animated icon. If you have a relatively simple animated SVG, you can try running the main.dart command line tool within the bin folder of this repository: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/dev/tools/vitool. I haven't attempted yet, but I will try and report back if I find any issues. The output should look like the following:

```dart
const _AnimatedIconData _$menu_arrow = _AnimatedIconData(
  Size(48.0, 48.0),
  <_PathFrames>[
    _PathFrames(
      opacities: <double>[
        1.0,
        1.0,
        1.0,
        1.0,
        1.0,
        1.0,
        1.0,
(...)
```

Answer (score -2):

You need 3 things for custom animations

1. Animation Controller
2. Tween
3. Animation

Simple example below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimationsPractice extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimationsPracticeState createState() => _AnimationsPracticeState();
}

class _AnimationsPracticeState extends State<AnimationsPractice> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        vsync: this);

   animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.purple, end: Colors.red[700]).animate(controller);

    controller.forward();

    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
        print(animation.value);
      }
      else if(status == AnimationStatus.dismissed){
        controller.forward();
      }
    });

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
      });
      print(controller.value);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Heart Beat'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
          size: animation.value * 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: OP wanted to transition between 2 icons, not get pulse animation for the same icon